# Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 throws an exception while image editing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Following image editing operations generate exception in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 on multiple images (all that I tried, PNG-s and JPG-s) in my project:

```
Click and Drag to Pan
Click and Drag to Zoom
Zoom Image to Actual Size
Fit in Window
Fit Image Width in Window
Show or Hide Grid
Show or Hide R, G, B, A channel
Show or Hide Alpha Checkerboard pattern
```

This is exception text from popup dialog (it is always the same):

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

### The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

### OK

I can edit/save these images from VS without a problem.

I can zoom in/out in VS using Ctrl-MouseWheel but crashes still occur whenever I use any of buttons I pointed in screenshot.

I can zoom them in MS Paint without any issues.

Changing Visual Experience settings (https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2894215?wa=wsignin1.0) doesn't help.

Installing latest AMD video drivers didn't help.

Disabling second monitor (I have 2) didn't help.

Tried booting in Safe Mode so that generic video drivers are used but VS 2013 won't start in Safe Mode.

There is another desktop of the same hardware/OS configuration (except it is single monitor) that runs RTM VS 2013 Premium (no updates installed) and it doesn't experience this problem.

Does anyone know to fix this? Or how to find out what module is not found? I checked Event log and there is nothing there related to it.

**This is probably relevant:** Running devenv.exe /log produces this error in the log when solution opens (but before I even try to open bitmap for editing):

> Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID
>   'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop' is already loaded at
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON
>   FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK...
>             C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS
>   KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\

[image: Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 unhandled exception]

Comment: Have you tried to repair your Visual Studio installation?

Comment: No, I didn't and I am reluctant to try. Other than that I don't experience any issues. Is it documented anywhere what exactly VS repair does?

Comment: You may have no other choice.  A repair installation should reset the installation back to the way it was first installed thus repairing any problems with visual studio.  You may have to reapply updates.  If the problem still exists after the repair, something external to visual studio is the culprit.

Comment: I turned VS logging on and added information from the log that may be relevant to my OP

Comment: It is a DLL load error.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to find out what DLL that might be.  And sure, a repair is strongly indicated here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by VS2013 installing version 8.1 tools automatically that conflict with version 8.0 tools previously installed with VS2012.

**Workaround Solution**

1. Control Panel - Programs and Features
2. Select Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
3. Select Change
4. Select Modify
5. Unselect anything having to do with developing Windows apps/programs
6. Save and restart either VS2012 or VS2013

The permanent solution would be for M$ to allow us to have those tools side-by-side.  But until they do we have to choose which version of VS we do certain types of development with.

Comment: I have this error but in 2015, no VS2012 or VS2013 installed,

Comment: @JuanZamudio Well, did the workaround I provided solve your problem or is it now obsolete in VS2015? Thanks.